# ag-grid, how to not show empty group header?

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I did nearly the same as the sample (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-groups/#suppress-span-header-height)

and it shows like this:

[my grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6gwl.png)

here is the code I copied and pasted below from the sample.

could you help me how can I fix this?

```
import React, {useState, useCallback, useRef, useMemo} from "react";

// MUI
import { Stack, Box } from "@mui/material";
...

const Vcode = () => {
 
  //grid test
  interface IOlympicData {
    athlete: string;
    age: number;
    country: string;
    year: number;
    date: string;
    sport: string;
    gold: number;
    silver: number;
    bronze: number;
    total: number;
  }

  const containerStyle = useMemo(() => ({ width: '100%', height: '600px' }), []);
  const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({ height: '600px', width: '100%' }), []);
  const [rowDataTest, setRowDataTest] = useState<IOlympicData[]>();
  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState<(ColDef | ColGroupDef)[]>([
    {
      headerName: 'Athlete Details',
      children: [{ field: 'athlete' }, { field: 'country' }],
    },
    {
      field: 'age',
      width: 90,
    },
  ]);
  const defaultColDef = useMemo<ColDef>(() => {
    return {
      sortable: true,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true,
    };
  }, []);
  const onGridReady = useCallback((params: GridReadyEvent) => {
    fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((dataTest: IOlympicData[]) => setRowDataTest(dataTest));
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div style={containerStyle}>
        <div style={gridStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
          <AgGridReact<IOlympicData>
            rowData={rowDataTest}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Vcode;
```

I want to display an ungrouped column with a rowspan of 2.

like the sample below:

[smaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXKtk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version of Ag-Grid. I experienced the same thing (only using React) on version 29.2.0. When I updated to version 30.2.1 (which is the latest version as of this post) the problem went away.